# TypeScript Error 2304 when using interface

Tags: angular, typescript

Working on an angular project and I created an interface file where I do two things:

Define an interface:

```
export interface tableHeader {
    roundNumber: string;
    eighteenHoleScore: string;
    nineHoleScore: string;
    courseRating: string;
    slopeRating: string;
    scoreDifferential: string;
}
```

Create a variable to hold an array of strings:

```
export const roundHeader = [
    roundNumber: 'Round Number',
    eighteenHoleScore: '18 Hole Score',
    nineHoleScore: '9 Hole Score',
    courseRating: 'Course Rating',
    slopeRating: 'Slope Rating',
    scoreDifferential: 'Score Differential'
]
```

I am getting the above 2304 error for each of my variables created in the `roundHeader` const.  I looked through the site and didn't see anything to answer this and I found on google a lot of things relating to 'require' but in this circumstance it has nothing to do with require.

I am just trying to create an interface to define each variable type, then create static text in the same file so that I can export this static text to multiple pages of my app.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: You might want to replace `[` with `{` and `]` with `}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You need to define `roundHeader` type.
2. Array will only contain **values**, not **key-vales**.

If you want to use the interface with array, use array of objects:

```
interface tableHeader {
  roundNumber: string;
  eighteenHoleScore: string;
  nineHoleScore: string;
  courseRating: string;
  slopeRating: string;
  scoreDifferential: string;
}

const roundHeader: tableHeader[] = [
  {
    roundNumber: "Round Number",
    eighteenHoleScore: "18 Hole Score",
    nineHoleScore: "9 Hole Score",
    courseRating: "Course Rating",
    slopeRating: "Slope Rating",
    scoreDifferential: "Score Differential",
  },
];
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAjHARgGwgCQnAE2mQG8BYAKGWuSgHsBXEAgOQYFt1oAuZAZzBRQAcwDclGsgjBhAC0gQQOOtgDKCOlAi8BQkGIk0QoXCojrN2-oJHiqNDQyh8IAJThgROm-ruS+mHQADm4eXtZ6BvbUfBpaACLAMDDQip5wmN6RdgC+lBIaIAK0jMx4hDyoGNjlRFAA2gC6yAC8yPXk0SVMrBxcULwA5K6lBMhsnNCDADSG1NJyCkpmFlpDAIwAHMjK2MirEDNzyMYgpmpxVoMAnDtm+5dHXY7OoZ76QwDCjK-I7u-CJ7+QIhf7hQaqEEoMH6IE0WKWRLJVLgYAZIYHZBIlJaVEZQZ5CiNIA)

Alternative to your answer:

if you want static texts, why not use `enum`?:

```
enum TableHeader{
    roundNumber= "Round Number",
    eighteenHoleScore= "18 Hole Score",
    nineHoleScore= "9 Hole Score",
    courseRating= "Course Rating",
    slopeRating= "Slope Rating",
    scoreDifferential= "Score Differential",
   }

   const somewhereNeedsRoundNumber = TableHeader.roundNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your case is what our friend Jastria Rahmat showed. However, just to clarify some things here:

When you declared your interface, everything was fine, but when created your const, you didn't explicitly say what type was that const, what could be done by doing `export const roundHeader: tableHeader` (prefer starting type/interface names with capital letters).

Another problem is that your `roundHeader` is an array and your tried to add **key-value** pairs to it, while the correct would be creating an JS object instead of that array, becoming like this:

```
export const roundHeader: TableHeader = {
    roundNumber: 'Round Number',
    eighteenHoleScore: '18 Hole Score',
    nineHoleScore: '9 Hole Score',
    courseRating: 'Course Rating',
    slopeRating: 'Slope Rating',
    scoreDifferential: 'Score Differential'
};
```

In case you really want an array of objects that contain those fields, just follow the answer from Jastria, getting something similar to:

```
export const roundHeader: TableHeader[] = [
    {
        roundNumber: "Round Number",
        eighteenHoleScore: "18 Hole Score",
        nineHoleScore: "9 Hole Score",
        courseRating: "Course Rating",
        slopeRating: "Slope Rating",
        scoreDifferential: "Score Differential",
    },
    // ...
    // other objects with the same fields
]
```